# Rails4 - Devise - User can generates Partners, Partners are User Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, polymorphism

I'm using rails 4 and Devise authentication.

User sign-up requires only email, then, after email-verification, askng for username, firstname, lastname & password to be filled.

User has(owns) teams, in which he cans add partners.

Partners are User Class since they share the same attributes.

It's a pretty simple logic, but since Devise do a lot of operations solely, I'm wondering if it"s the right track to follow, I mean sharing the User model for users and partners, instead of having a dedicated model for each.

Per example, I have these things touchy in mind:

> **How can I "auto activate" my partners, meaning overriding the devise activation process ?**

--> Partners would then be visible instantly inside the app

--> Partners wouldn't be allowed to log-in obviously

Later logic:

> **Later, if a user try to sign-up and his email already exists in database it will :**

--> Check for user status

----> if it"s a partner, then a new account is created with status "user"

---->if it's a user, a password reminder would be sent by email

> **MORE INFO ABOUT LOGIC**

Users that are owner of teams ( = registered users) will have the status "user"
Users gererated, called Partners, will have the status "partners", but are from User class

Thus said, a User, wil be able to create more than one partners, and those partners may have the same email (say that they are not in the same team).
I can kill this duplication problem with find or create, because all the partners are created by the same user.

Now, imagine that many users have common partners. User1 create partner@gmail.com, and User2 create partner@gmail.com
Here, Devise will put its veto and block creation.

> Why Do I want to preserve partner for each, and why do I want to keep
>   partner & user with the same email ?

--> Partners has profile. I want a User to be able to create the profile he wants for the partner (avatar etc).

--> Partners can act in differents teams with different profile occupation (say quaterback, or something like that), thus each user can create his own profile for a unique partner@email.com

--> If a user sign-up (to become an owner, kind of an official profile), and is present as a partner in few teams, then the owner of the teams well be asked to swich profile from the one he created to the "official one"

I agree, it's a bit complicated.

For now, I store the "owner" status in a dedicated row in User model.
I have a joined table for the many to many relationship between Card and Partner.
This way, I can easily update the partner_id with his new "official profile" id if requested by the user then delete the line of the "non official" profile in User model

MY problems are actually Devise authentication with roles to block partner sign-in attempts (thats part answered below) and email uniqueness.

I hope that my explanations are clear, I apologize for my bad english.

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: As per your update, i feel there is a need for couple of models to keeps things separate and avoid unnecessary logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach as you mention here is fine. You can have partners and users in the same User table. As i understand `user has_many teams and team belongs_to user`
.User will be either a owner or partner in the team.

So when user adds partners, just create a method to take care of user creation. Have one more table which contains user_id, team_id and user_role (either 'user' or 'partner')

assuming db used is sql,

```
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :teams_users
      has_many :users, :through => :team_users
    end

    class TeamUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :team
      belongs_to :user
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :teams_users
      has_many :teams, :through => :teams_users
    end
```

Devise expects password, so you can set password and password_confirmation from your server side. Don't send a mail to user as you want to avoid the default devise way of authentication. Devise stores confirmed_at in user attribute which is set with a timestamp when the user clicks on the confirmation link. `Update this confirmed_at`
from backend either directly when users are added or may be as per your requirement. Once the partner's email id is registered, password set and confirmed_at available, the partner account is active.

Let's look into the second part when a user tried to signup/login either as a partner or user. To handle this, change the sign_in behaviour of user. Inherit devise controllers and check for user role from the users_team table when user tries to sign_up. Have a more clear idea, in case of user having two roles in two different teams will be confusing.

Also even though the user status is partner, new account should not be created as devise considers email id as unique by default and since the user object is already created, unless you try to change this. Sending a password reminder in both the case looks good still you can work on the functionality as per the application needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these infos, that's very helpfull. I'll add info in the question (for readability) regarding the complete use of this double profile, because it seems to be problematic for the email that isn't unique in my supposed logic.